# How to change range component code in IONIC 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have to changes some codes in ionic range component. in ionic 3 the ionic components codes are in node_modules/ionic-angular folder but in IONIC 4 I can't find where are the components files? 
Is there anybody know how can I customize the ionic 4 range component in the code? Or where can I find the ionic components codes?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you need to customize?

Comment: I think it's here node_modules\@ionic\core\dist\collection\components\range\range.js

Comment: @Monomachus, Yes I already found this folder and do some changes but my changes are not reflecting in the app!

Comment: @Monomachus, for example I need to prevent user to tap on range component for changing moving the range slider, user must swipe the range slider. I did this in ionic 3 as I mentioned.